# The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am facing following error while running a spring boot application. I am trying to implement custom login using spring security.

```
2019-07-24 11:47:25.734  WARN 7640 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetails' defined in file [D:\Swapnil\downloaded code\Web-Wallet\target\classes\com\fidel\webwallet\service\impl\CustomUserDetails.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetails': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Adding classes bellow that I feel related to this error.

CustomUserDetails

```
    /**
 * 
 */
package com.fidel.webwallet.service.impl;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.fidel.webwallet.model.UserInfo;

/**
 * @author Swapnil
 *
 */
@Component
public class CustomUserDetails extends UserInfo implements UserDetails {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public CustomUserDetails(UserInfo userInfo) {
        super(userInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getUserPassword().getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getEmailId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
}
```

Model Class "UserInfo"

```
package com.fidel.webwallet.model;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

import com.fidel.webwallet.commons.CommonUtils;

/**
 * @author Swapnil
 *
 */
@Entity
public class UserInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer custId;
    private String userName;
    private String address;
    private String contactNo;
    private String emailId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userInfo")
    private Password password;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public UserInfo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public UserInfo(UserInfo userInfo) {
        this.userName = userInfo.getUserName();
        this.password.setPassword(userInfo.getUserPassword().getPassword());
        this.roles = userInfo.getRoles();
    }

    public Integer getCustId() {
        return custId;
    }

    public void setCustId(Integer custId) {
        this.custId = custId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getContactNo() {
        return contactNo;
    }

    public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the password
     */
    public Password getUserPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * @param password the password to set
     */
    public void setUserPassword(Password password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * @return the roles
     */
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    /**
     * @param roles the roles to set
     */
    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String validate() {
        String emptyFiled = "";

        if (CommonUtils.isEmpty(emailId)) {
            emptyFiled = "email";
        }

        if (CommonUtils.isEmpty(this.contactNo)) {
            emptyFiled = "contact";
        }

        return emptyFiled;
    }

}
```

Web Security configuration

```
package com.fidel.webwallet.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

/**
 * @author Swapnil
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WalletWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/wallet/user/register", "/wallet/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/js/*.js").permitAll().antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll().antMatchers("**/fonts/**")
                .permitAll().antMatchers("/webfonts/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/wallet/user/postReq").loginPage("/wallet/user/login")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").successForwardUrl("/wallet/user/home");

        http.logout().permitAll();
    }

    /*
     * @Bean public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws
     * Exception { return authenticationManager();
     * 
     * }
     */

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new PasswordEncoder() {

            @Override
            public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return rawPassword.toString();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If given information is not enough then let me know ill try to add remain calssess

Comment: You somehow mix the concepts of Spring beans (business behaviour) and Entities (state) - please take a step backwards and explain what you are actually trying to achieve, your current approach does not show it clearly.

Comment: I am simply trying to include spring security to my application and want custom login form for user authentication. I have added a GitHub link.

Comment: Data objects (such as a `UserDetails`) should not be Spring beans (service objects, `@Component`).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@Component` from your `CustomUserDetails` class.

A class cannot be both an [entity](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-spring-data-jpa) and a [component](http://zetcode.com/springboot/component/) at the same time.

In your example `UserInfo` is na entity (class used for database storage), so when `CustomUserDetails` extends it, it should behave like a wrapper for the said entity, adding additional functionality. I guess this is what your initial intention was.

A class marged by `@Component` annotation must be injectable, just like `@Service`, `@Controller` or `@Repository`. These classes should be stateless and Spring must be capable of creating instance without issue.